# How to exclude a string

Tags: regex

I want to exclude string "VSS" from the message

> The VSS writer ran out of memory

The regEx I am using for pattern match is

```
[O,o]ut of [M,m]emory
```

but if VSS comes in the message, I want to exclude that entire message. Is this possible?

Comment: The commas in the character classes are not part of the syntax. They will match commas. They should be removed. I tried to edit the post but can't because "Edits must be at least 6 characters". (Yay for arbitrary rules like that.)

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this using a negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?i)^(?!.*VSS).*out of memory
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?i)           # Make the regex case-insensitive
^              # Match the start of the string
(?!.*VSS)      # Assert that there is no "VSS" in the string
.*             # Match any number of characters
out of memory  # Match "out of memory"
```

By the way, `[O,o]` matches an `O`, an `o` ***or a `,`***, so that's probably not what you meant.